# R.java doesn't update

Tags: java, android

I have problem when programming android application,
when I make any change the R.java file doesn't update
I tried to change it manually but it isn't work
I deleted project an create a new one but still have a problem
what should I do ?

Comment: Are you using the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: The R.java file is GENERATED. So you cannot/should not/must not edit it manually...

Answer (score 2):

**1.  Don't** do anything to the R.java file.

**2. Delete** the R file, and then let it get **generated by itself**.

**3. Clean** your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate R.java file yourself. It is compiler generated file. but yeah, you can delete and re-build the project. Hopefully you will get updated file generated.

Comment: I don't know how rebuild it, can you help me ?

Comment: Clean it..and compile it....like other projects..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once.

1. Verify you have [Android ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) updated.
2. Clean your project (right-click on it and select **Clean** option)
3. **Never change R file by yourself it is intended to be auto-generated**

Answer (score 0):

Build your project again.It may be solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there are any errors in your xml files. If so, R.java will not update.